# How to sync configuration between multiple developers' environments

Tags: configuration

D8 Configuration management is really awesome and easy to use when there's only one developer working on a project. We are running into challenges in keeping configuration synced between environments when more than one developer is introduced to a project at the same time.

Example:

- Developer A is working on feature A. Exports configuration to their feature branch and pushes it to a shared develop branch.
- At the same time, developer B is working on feature B and does the same thing - pushes feature configuration to the shared develop branch.

How do you import feature A and feature B concurrently?

Answer (score 3):

Don't push to the develop branch directly. You should have a branch and merge strategy. If using GitHub or GitLab or similar, you would do a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) of *your* branch to develop.

A common strategy (or one of) is the [Git Flow workflow](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh). Some links to explain Git Flow:

- https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

There are a handful of strategies, use whatever will fit for your team.

One of the few circumstances I ran into with merge conflicts was if someone was working on something touching the same configuration areas as another person.. we avoided this by just coordinating the work well.

Comment: Oh, i see. So within a pull request, ONLY the configuration files the developer has modified get merged in?

Comment: Yes, at a high level its a merge of the changes. Check the GitHub link I added. I don't know if you are using GitHub or whatever service or just raw Git, either way, don't push directly to a mainline branch in a multi person team. You will have conflicts and issues every step of the way.

Comment: Ok - good to know. We use bitbucket but are not taking advantage of Git Flow. That looks to be a great strategy. Thanks Kevin